# Filling NULL values during deserialization (.net json) or during serialization (XmlSerializer) in C#

Tags: c#, json, xml, serialization, deserialization

what I am doing in my code is receiving a JSON file and deserialize it into my custom object through:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyObjectType>(response);
```

At this point MyObject will have some string properties set to NULL and I will serialize this object to an XML by using:

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyObjectType));
        var XmlCase = String.Empty;

        using (var stringWriter = new StringWriter())
        {
            using (XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(stringWriter))
            {
                serializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, MyObject);
                XmlCase = stringWriter.ToString();
            }
        }
```

What I want is either replacing those NULL values with an empty string (possibly I would like this to happen through some setting) during the JsonConvert.DeserializeObject or I would like this to happen during the XML serialization. What I would like to avoid in either cases is parsing my object searching for NULL values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to specify a default 'empty' value on the strings that are currently null:

```
string myString = "";
```

And then you need to tell the JSON (de)serializer to ignore null values and populate the fields with their default values using a settings object.

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings() {
    NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
    DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Populate,
}
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyObject>(Response, settings);
```

It should now behave the way you desire.